# Allow multipe context to be combined into a single context (AND Functionality) rather than each context working individually

Tags: entities

In Personalize[https://www.drupal.org/project/personalize] module there is only OR condition while targeting the fields.

Currently the instructions provide for context are as follows: "If you choose multiple contexts for an option, then the rule will apply if the visitor has any of the specified contexts."

There would be a lot of power in the ability to combine contexts, for example, if user has A AND B, than C rather than just if user has A OR B, than C.

Comment: This sounds to me as a feature request, rather than something you can do. However, I'm not really familiar with the Personalize module, so I can't be 100% sure. Did you try posting this in the module's issue queue?